# How do I scroll a webpage automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

When the website loads I want a gif to be displayed and after the animation ends I want the page to automatically scroll up without clicking any button and reveal my main site. I want the gif to load automatically every time, not only the first time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I tried scrollTop and jquery page slide. They use buttons. I want the page to slide up after the gif animation ends.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for JavaScript to know when a GIF animation ends. You could use individual static images and animate them with a timer using JS, however.

Comment: Does this sound like something the user would enjoy?  It almost sounds like a Flash splash page that no one liked back in 2000.  Users typically don't like content moving without their control.

Answer (score 4):

Time the gif. Put a timeout that when X time is passed it scrolls.
Maybe its a nicer idea to time it and then hide it instead of scroll.

Though impossible to time because you are bound to loading time of the GIF

Comment: isn't there a way to run jQuery when a given element loads?

Comment: $('img').load(function() {
    // find the related link or click event and enable/add it
});

Comment: so if you wanted to wait for an image to load, you could do `<img id="myimage">` and do `$("#myimage").load(function() {});`

Comment: This method is a shortcut for .on('load', handler).

The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/